# Transfer data in Thymeleaf

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I have two input value like this

```
<input type="text" th:field="*{itemID}"placeholder="Bidding id" class="form- 
control" required />
------------
<input type="hidden" th:field="*{item.id}" />
```

okay so how can i put the value of item.id field into itemID ?. I tried like below but it didn't work

```
<input type="hidden" th:field="*{itemID}" th:value="*{item.id}" 
placeholder="Bidding id" class="form-control" required />
```

update 
i tried to make it like this, but it still not work

```
<input type="hidden" th:name="*{itemID}" th:value="1"
placeholder="Bidding id" class="form-control" required />
```

Comment: th:field sets the name and the value. If you want to do this manually try setting th:name and th:value instead

Comment: it didn't work sir

Comment: What html output do you get? An what do you expect?

Comment: i try to debug it in eclipse and it said the itemID value is always equal 0 when i execute the funtion

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
<input type="hidden" th:field="*{itemID}" th:value="${item.id}" placeholder="Bidding id" class="form-control" required />
```

replace the `*` by `$` in `th:value` attribute